# Starting position with fgetcsv

Tags: php, handle, fgetcsv

I have a script that runs every 20 minutes that imports log data from a CSV into my database.  Some log files may have 20 entries and some may have over 400,000.  My challenge is this....the log files may change or grow within the intervals that my routine runs.  On the next import, I'd like to pick up at the last log entry that was imported during the previous routine run instead of having to drop the data from my table and reimport the entire log file.  Is this even possible?

At the moment, my code is:

```
if (($handle = fopen("/STORAGE/logfile.txt", "r")) !== FALSE)
    {
        while (($columnsUser = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE)
            {
                etc
```

So, for example, if at 12:20, the log file has 1000 entires, I import all of them.  At 12:40, I'd like to start at line 1001 if there are more.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with ftell and fseek.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.ftell.php
http://php.net/manual/en/function.fseek.php
Store the location in a database for later reference.